# Check if CLLocation is in Shape?

Tags: ios, shapes, cllocation

Im looking for a way to detect if the user is in The Netherlands or in Belgium. I don't want to call an API or use the users telephone services, so everything needs to be done locally and should be something easy and quick, small check.  I have the users location each second and want to check each minute.

Goal:
The user is travelling with our app and I want to show a different view when he/she arrived Belgium/Netherlands.

I've found two shape files from http://www.diva-gis.org/datadown with Netherlands and Belgium. These files are quite small and now Im looking for a way to create this method:

```
- (BOOL)isUserInNetherlands:(CLLocation)location;
```

which should check the location is it is in the content of the shapefile.

The shapefile for the Netherlands looks something like this:

[image: netherlands shapefile]

I can convert the shapefile to a sqlLite database but not idea what to do next.

Any idea's?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to do this is:

1) convert the shapefile to geoJson

2) load the geoJson file data in your code.

3) create polygons from these gps points (note: CountryDetectorController is my controller class)

```
+ (MKPolygon *)overlaysFromPolygons:(NSArray *)polygons title:(NSString *)title;
{
    NSMutableArray *interiorPolygons = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:[polygons count] - 1];
    for (int i = 1; i < [polygons count]; i++) {
        [interiorPolygons addObject:[CountryDetectorController polygonFromPoints:polygons[i] interiorPolygons:nil]];
    }

    MKPolygon *overlayPolygon = [CountryDetectorController polygonFromPoints:polygons[0] interiorPolygons:interiorPolygons];
    overlayPolygon.title = title;


    return overlayPolygon;
}

+ (MKPolygon *)polygonFromPoints:(NSArray *)points interiorPolygons:(NSArray *)polygons;
{
    NSInteger numberOfCoordinates = [points count];
    CLLocationCoordinate2D *polygonPoints = malloc(numberOfCoordinates * sizeof(CLLocationCoordinate2D));

    NSInteger index = 0;
    for (NSArray *pointArray in points) {
        polygonPoints[index] = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake([pointArray[1] floatValue], [pointArray[0] floatValue]);
        index++;
    }

    MKPolygon *polygon;

    if (polygons) {
        polygon = [MKPolygon polygonWithCoordinates:polygonPoints count:numberOfCoordinates interiorPolygons:polygons];
    } else {
        polygon = [MKPolygon polygonWithCoordinates:polygonPoints count:numberOfCoordinates];
    }
    free(polygonPoints);

    return polygon;
}
```

4) create a CGPath from the polygon

```
+ (CGPathRef)pathForPolygon:(MKPolygon*)aPolygon;
{
    CGMutablePathRef mpr = CGPathCreateMutable();

    MKMapPoint *polygonPoints = aPolygon.points;
    size_t nCount = aPolygon.pointCount;

    for (int p = 0; p < nCount; p++)
    {
        MKMapPoint mp = polygonPoints[p];

        if (p == 0)
            CGPathMoveToPoint(mpr, NULL, mp.x, mp.y);
        else
            CGPathAddLineToPoint(mpr, NULL, mp.x, mp.y);
    }

    return mpr; //Keep in memory;
}
```

5) check if coordinate is in CGPath (pathsBelgium is an array with NSValue of CGPaths)

```
- (void)checkCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)coordinate;
{
    MKMapPoint mapPoint = MKMapPointForCoordinate(coordinate);
    CGPoint mapPointAsCGP = CGPointMake(mapPoint.x, mapPoint.y);

    BOOL userIsInBelgium = FALSE;
    for(NSValue *valuePathBE in pathsBelgium)
    {
        CGPathRef pathBe;
        [valuePathBE getValue:&pathBe];

        BOOL pointInBelgium = CGPathContainsPoint(pathBe, NULL, mapPointAsCGP, FALSE);
        if(pointInBelgium)
        {
            userIsInBelgium = TRUE;
            break;
        }
    }

    NSLog(@"User is in Belgium: %i", userIsInBelgium);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A simpler method would be to get the user's location and then do a reverse geocode. Then you can extract the country from Apple's API instead of doing all the work yourself.
More here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/UsingGeocoders/UsingGeocoders.html

Comment: Thanks but I asked a way without the use of an API call. I ment here without a call to another webservice where internet is required. Reason for this is that I want to keep the data traffic as low as possible (foreign country data traffic) and it should work without internet as well.

Comment: Sorry, missed that. Note, the data traffic for this operation is going to be very minimal, but fair enough.

Comment: Do you only care about whether a user is in Belgium/Netherlands, and if they're not in either you don't care about them at all? If so you could test proximity to a point that is furthest from the border for each country.

Comment: Yes! Well maybe in the future more countries but not all countries. How would the proximity test work ? Can I export the border from the shape file?

Comment: The border seems relatively straight, so I was thinking you could just pick a point that's far from it on each side and do a simple distance check.

But it still wouldn't work well for places near the border, which defeats the whole purpose. And if you're dealing with the shape of the border you might as well just use the shapefile.